# How to fix installation of a package by Composer outside vendor folder

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe

I am migrating a SilverStripe 3 website to SilverStripe 4 and in that process, I resorted to the [silverstripe-ldap](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-ldap/) module. It comes with a dependency to [symbiote/silverstripe-queuedjobs](https://github.com/symbiote/silverstripe-queuedjobs/)

The problem that I have is that symbiote/silverstripe-queuedjobs has its files installed by Composer in a `queuedjobs` folder at the same level than `vendor`, instead of being in `vendor` like all of the other dependencies.

Is it possible to force it to be installed in folder `vendor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All SilverStripe 3 modules install into the root project folder, rather than into the `vendor` folder.

In SilverStripe 4 this is still supported, but by default most modules (including all core and supported modules) install into the `vendor` folder.

If you've still got one in your root folder, you probably are installing an incompatible SilverStripe 3 version of that module. You should check [the module on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/symbiote/silverstripe-queuedjobs) to find which version is SilverStripe 4 compatible (use `^4.5`) and update your Composer constraints.

Comment: I was using `"silverstripe/recipe-cms": "^4.5.1"`, but I was using `"silverstripe/ldap": "1.0"` which is compatible with SS 4, but still led to this issue. Once I added the caret and used `"^1.0"`, the folder of the third-party dependency was moved to the `vendor` folder.